# If $M$ has a largest proper submodule, then $ M$ is directly indecomposable

Tags: direct-sum

How to prove ;

"Every module $M$, which has a largest proper submodule or, in the set of non-zero submodules, a smallest submodule, is directly indecomposable?"

Comment: Yes, I can. Can you?

Comment: I will be pleasure if you write the proof, i couldnt proof it